# Why are these linear functions/operators? (Mathematical Methods... by Boas, Problem #3.7.13)

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I had these questions on a homework of mine. My answers were marked incorrect, but I'm not sure why.

> Let $D$ stand for $\frac{d}{dx}$, $D^2$ for $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$, $D^3$ for $\frac{d^3}{dx^3}$, and so on...
>
> - Is $D^2 + 2D + 1$ linear?
> - Is $x^2D^2 - 2xD + 7$ a linear operator?

My answer:

Let $f(x) = D^2 + 2D + 1$. Then $f(x_1) + f(x_2) = (D_{x_1}^2 + 2D_{x_1} + 1) + (D_{x_2}^2 + 2D_{x_2} + 1)$
$~~= (\frac{d^2}{dx_1^2} + 2\frac{d}{dx_1} + 1) + (\frac{d^2}{dx_1^2} + 2\frac{d}{dx_1} + 1)$
$~~= D_{x_1+x_2}^2 + 2D_{x_1 + x_2} + 2 \ne f(x_1 + x_2) = D_{x_1+x_2}^2 + 2D_{x_1 + x_2} + 1$

So $f(x)$ is not linear.

Let $g(x) = x^2D^2 - 2xD + 7$. By a similar argument, $g(x_1) + g(x_2)$ will have a $+14$ term, while $g(x_1 + x_2)$ will only have a $+7$ term, so $g(x)$ is not linear.

Apparently, both of these things **are** linear. I've got no idea why—I checked with the solution manual to the textbook and it also says they're linear. I know that the derivative itself is linear, but don't the $+1$ and $+7$ terms mess things up in terms of linearity?

Comment: What you had to explore was the linearity of $(D^2+2D+1)(f+\alpha g)$ resp. $(x^2D^2−2xD+7)(f+\alpha g)$. And where does the second variable come from? In the given context, $x$ is one real variable.

Comment: Wouldn't $(D^2+2D+1)(f+\alpha g) \ne (D^2+2D+1)(f) + (D^2+2D+1)(\alpha g)$ still? (Also, which second variable?)

Comment: You were using derivatives for $x_1$ and $x_2$. And $α$ is of course a scalar. Where do you see the inequality coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be getting confused as to what these operators are actually operating on. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the vector space of (smooth) functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. The differentiation operator $D$ is an operator

\begin{equation}
D: \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F},
\end{equation}

i.e. it maps a function to another function (not numbers to numbers). When you write something like "$f(x) = D^2 + 2D + 1$" this makes it seem like $D$ is a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, which it isn't. And this is why the $+1$ and $+7$ don't "mess things up" (here "1" represents the identity operator $\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}$, and not "1" as a real number). So, as stated in the comments, your goal is to verify the equality

\begin{equation}
(D^2 + 2D + 1)(f + \alpha g) = (D^2 + 2D +1)(f) + \alpha (D^2 + 2D + 1)(g),
\end{equation}

for all $f,g \in \mathcal{F}$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Does this clear things up?

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't quite understand. Would you mind expanding the operation out for me? When I see $(D^2 + 2D + 1)(f)$, I think the second derivative of $f$, two times the first derivative of $f$, plus one. Here, the $+1$ is just $(1)(f)$? Edit: I see now. That **is** what the $+1$ term is. Excellent, thank you.